# serving nginx static files from a subdomain (remove server)

Tags: nginx

I'm using nginx to route all incoming requests for a subdomain to a specific server. How do I configure nginx to also serve the static files from that same server?

```
server {
    server_name subdomain.XYZ.com;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://10.123.456.78:8000;
        proxy_pass_header Server;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_read_timeout 864000;
    }

    location /static/ {
        autoindex on;
        alias /static/;
    }
}
```

In this case, all incoming requests to subdomain.XYZ.com are rerouted to 10.123.456.78:8000. But all requests for static files are still on the local server (the one running nginx).

How do I route the static files to the remote server? And then how do I enable both caching and gzip compression of those static files?

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple:

```
gzip on;
gzip_types text/plain application/json;
# or gzip *; for all

proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:10m;

location /static/? {
    proxy_cache one;
    proxy_pass http://10.123.456.78:8000/path/to/static/files;
}
```

I would recommend gzipping them from the source instead however (on server `10.123.456.78`).

Comment: This doesn't work, nginx ignores the /static url (I get a 404 Not Found)

Comment: You will need to add a question mark after the trailing slash to make it optional. Updated answer

Comment: Still doesn't work. Also, port 10.123.456.78:8000 is running flask/gunicorn - whereas these static files are predominantly image files. I don't want flask/gunicorn to serve the images files, I want nginx to manage and cache them.

Comment: Then you will need nginx on that machine as well. On that machine is where you should enable nginx to gzip the data.